Why is it possible to reach one docker container from another with the loopback address?
So I've been given the task to write a docker compose file for three containers. A frontend container, a backend container and a database container.
What I have done is this, and it works:
##TODO##

version: "3"
services:
  angular:
    container_name: angular
    build: ./frontend
    depends_on:
      - spring-boot
      - db
    ports:
      - 80:80
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      API_URL: http://127.0.0.1:8080/
    networks:
      - docker-spring-angular

  spring-boot:
    container_name: spring-boot
    build: ./backend
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    environment:
      spring.datasource.url: jdbc:mysql://db/test
      spring.datasource.username: test
      spring.datasource.password: test
    depends_on:
      - db
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - docker-spring-angular

  db:
    container_name: db
    image: mysql:latest
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: test
      MYSQL_USER: test
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: test
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    restart: unless-stopped
    cap_add:
      - SYS_NICE
    networks:
      - docker-spring-angular

networks:
  docker-spring-angular:

My question is: Why does it work? I can address the database using the hostname of the database container from within the spring-boot container. But this doesn't work with the API-URL in the angular container. If I use "http://spring-boot:8080/" it does not work. If I use the loopback address, it does work, but it should not, right? I don't want to use the IP address of the backend container because if someone configures docker with a different subnet, it won't work.

If I understand you correctly, then it works because your Angular app runs in a browser outside the docker network. So the connections are made from the browser and not from the container. You can only use the service names as hostnames in programs running in containers on the docker network.

as I have answered the similar question check answer on this post (even tho it was react based)
But core of the issue is:

Applications run in your browser, whereas if you deploy an application stack somewhere else, the REST of the services (APIs, DB and such) do not. So referencing your IP/DNS/localhost inside your application won't work, because there is nothing there. A container that contains a WEB application is there to only serve your browser


(client) files and then the JS and the logic are executed inside your browser, not the container.

I suspect this might be affecting your ability to connect to the backend.
To solve this you have two options.

Create an HTTP proxy as an additional service and your FE calls that proxy (set up a domain and routing), for instance, Nginx, Traefik, ... and that proxy then can reference your backend with the service name, since it does live in the same environment than API.





Expose the HTTP port directly from the container and then your FE can call remoteServerIP:exposedPort and you will connect directly to the container's interface. (NOTE: I do not recommend this way for real use, only for testing direct connectivity without any proxy)


